# Google OAuth in PHP without using webview

Tags: php, webview, user-agent, google-oauth

I have recently developed an application that allows for users to login via google. It has only just come to my attention (in testing) that google do not allow for OAuth to be accessed in a devices webview.

My current google login code is as follows

```
    $client = new \Google_Client();
    $url = 'myurl';
    $client->setAuthConfigFile('../myconfigfile.com.json');
    $client->setRedirectUri($url);
    $client->addScope(\Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY);
    if (!isset($_GET['code'])) {
        /* Google App Client Id */
        define('CLIENT_ID', 'myid');
        /* Google App Client Secret */
        define('CLIENT_SECRET', 'mysecret');
        /* Google App Redirect Url */
        define('CLIENT_REDIRECT_URL', $url);
        $googleURL = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?scope=' . urlencode('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me') . '&redirect_uri=' . urlencode(CLIENT_REDIRECT_URL) . '&response_type=code&client_id=' . CLIENT_ID . '&access_type=online';
        header("Location: " .$googleURL);
        exit();
    }
```

This code works fine on a browser, but when I run it on a device (currently testing on iPad), it errors out and throw the issue 'disallowed user agent'.

How would I get it so that it loads in a browser app, instead of a web-view, or if this is not do-able, is there a workaround using php?

Answer (score 0):

you need to authenticate server-side, not client-side with a header redirect...

see: [Using OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/web-app).

while one actually **can** login client-side on iOS webview, when either adding

```
<preference name="OverrideUserAgent" value="Mozilla/5.0 Google"/>
```

into `config.xml` - or when overriding the user agent string with JavaScript:

```
webview.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Chrome/56.0.0.0 Mobile");
```

Comment: Possibly a stupid question, but how can I authenticate server side when I need the client side functionality for a user to select their account? My application needs the functionality for a user to be able to use their own google account, and I cant see how this can be achieved server side?

Comment: Also, apologies for any confusion but by application I meant web application. I do not have access to the webView property or a config.xml file

Comment: @user7070541 JavaScript is still able to set the user agent... while "Using OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications" explains how it would work with a server-side authentication flow. with the updated user agent string, you don't have to. here is an example https://ctrlq.org/code/20363-google-api-php-oauth2-example